# Drop a file from resources to a folder

Tags: vb.net

So I'm using:

```
IO.File.WriteAllBytes(Environ("/bin/") & "utorrent.exe", My.Resources.utorrent)
```

Which suppose to enter the folder "bin" and than drop the file `utorrent.exe`.

What it does is just dropping the file at the same place as the exe, not going into bin folder first.

Comment: Is your code not VB instead of C# because you use an `&` and no `;`

Comment: Edit also your title from C# to VB

Answer (score 0):

Why don't you use? :
`My.Computer.FileSystem.MoveFile
(My.Resources.utorrent,"C:\...bin\utorrent.exe")`

But you have to import System.IO

Check this:
https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/2t00swhw.aspx